# How to call 2010 excel.xlsm rather than 2003 in VBscript?

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, excel-2010

1)  I would like this to open in excel 2010 rather than 2003
Dim objExcel, objWorkbook

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("\\filepath.xls ")
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.Run "Test2"                                                     ‘Running a macro
objworkbook.Save

objWorkbook.Close False

objExcel.Quit


'Set objWorkbook = Nothing
'Set objExcel = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

2)  How do I assign the file as an excel file with a defined name – such that I can run Macros, Save and Close further down the code

```
Dim sXLPath
Set sXLPath = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
sXLPath.run "cmd.exe cd /C C:\WINDOWS\CCM\Launcher.exe /launch ""Microsoft Excel 2010"" "

WScript.Sleep 15000 'Sleeps for 15 seconds

CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("""\\filepath.xls""")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the version during the GetObject call

```
  Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application.15") '2013
  Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application.14") '2010
  Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application.12") '2007
  Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application.11") '2003
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. Believe my excel2010 is being called from a virtual drive? i.e. its not physically installed on my PC. Which is why I was trying to use the second option using command prompt. That successfully opens 2010 and the file but I am unable to assign to run macros, save and close. Any further ideas? Really appreciate your help!